# Why do we say that $\sqrt{-0} = -0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

According to [wikipedia's page on signed zeroes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), we agree that $\sqrt{-0} = -0$.

I would always have guessed that it would be $0i$, as $(0i)^2 = 0^2*i^2 = 0 * (-1) = -0$.

I know that my own reasoning is not correct, as $0i$ is a multiplication that would simply result in $0$, but why have we resorted to such an un-intuitive rule instead of creating a symbol to denote an "irrational zero"?

Comment: Did you read the whole wiki article?

Comment: You should be clear that you ar not talking about math, but about computer representations of numbers. Actually I'm not sure this is a question for MSE.

Comment: Is that the case, then? Does this rule only exist in these specific computer representations? Signed zeroes are not used exclusively in computer representations as far as I am aware, but I could indeed be misinterpreting the article.

Comment: Given that $-0$ is defined for computer science floating point arithmetic, it wouldn't make sense to introduce complex numbers. You either have to leave $\sqrt{-0}$ undefined, or define it as some version of $0$ in floating point arithmetic.

Comment: $+0$ and $-0$ are two computer representations of the same mathematical object ($0$)

Comment: @LeeWhite It's right in the first paragraph: " ordinary arithmetic, the number 0 does not have a sign, so that −0, +0 and 0 are identical. However, in computing, some number representations allow for the existence of two zeros, often denoted by −0 (negative zero) and +0 (positive zero)..."

Comment: @leonbloy No, they are not. Floating point numbers in computing are best seen as "ranges," and $-0$ and $+0$ represent different ranges of values.

Comment: this may have something to do with the "one's complement" representation of signed integers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement

Answer (score 2):

I think when the floating point type was invented the easiest thing to do for having positive and negative numbers was just introducing an additional bit that represents the sign. This now results in the problem that you have two representations for the number 0. Of course $0=-0$ in a mathematical sense.

But now you had to 'invent' rules on how to handle calculations and for making an universal convention like those IEEE standards the rules should be defined for *every case* possible. And $\sqrt{-0} = -0$ seems to be a pretty intuitive solution. Keep in mind that this is just the *rule* how to implement these standards, it has nothing to do with math since in math $\sqrt{-0} = \sqrt{0} = 0 = -0$.

Introducing a complex zero into the 'float' definition would require introducing complex numbers which wouldn't be a great idea since I think more thant 90 percent of all calculations that require floats do not need complex numbers but are inherently just real numbers so you would waste a lot of memory if you had to save the imaginary part (of value 0 most of the time) each time.

Comment: IEEE used this because the circuitry was easier.